# (dis)advantages of same processor with higher clock stock-frequency

Tags: cpu

Take as example [i5 9500T vs 9600T](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=191051,191052). According to specification, they are both the same hardware and differ only in the fact that 9600T has a higher frequency.

So apart from the higher frequency variant being faster, are there any other advantages or disadvantages. I am mainly interested in durability and stability in the long term (10 years) as higher clockspeeds on same hardware are related to higher voltages and temperature and thus wear.

Also, why does Intel make two versions, an not one? Besides marketing and financial aspects, are there any other reasons? i.e. are they optimizing the existing hardware within stability limits, and subsequently releasing it?

Note that I am *not* talking about overclocking, but stock frequency.

Answer (score 1):

The cynical view is that they are in fact exactly the same chip, but one passed a higher standards test before being clocked, stamped & marketed with the higher stock frequency.

Comment: Nothing cynical about it. Thats simply the fact.

Comment: To clarify @Tetsujin answer, there is variability of chip quality from the same die. Chips are tested, and "binned" by quality, with better performing chips being sold at a premium and pushed harder.